# Error in deploying C# UWP application

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to deploy a VS2017 UWP app to my raspberry pi 3 running Windows 10 iot core but I keep getting this error

[image: ERROR]

I've tried the following:
- Uninstall and Reinstall VS2017
- Clean and Rebuild Solution

Comment: Did it run once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to modify the name of the application **Identity** in the file *Package.appxmanifest*(open it with *View Code*) as a new Guid or other different value, and then deploy it again.